# Oozie Sqoop Workflow Refresh table

Tags: sqoop, oozie, impala, oozie-workflow

I update impala-tables by querying though workflow that created in Oozie Editor. (But who cares? Just "I update tables".

And, at the end of workflow, you need to run "refresh ". But I don't know how to do it. I need non-bash method.

Does Oozie can exec impala-ddl by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one additional shell action and call invalidate metadata from impala-shell command.

```
impala-shell -q "invalidate metada"
```

Comment: ok, I already did it (try it). But i can't - i have an "eggs" problem (like that: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Impala-schedule-with-oozie-tutorial/td-p/23906 ) And i try to avoid it by any other way to run "refrash"-command. Does there any other way?

Comment: Since there is no action called impala action, and shell is not your choice then you can do it use java (or similar technology) by using impala jdbc drive to run a query and refresh the table. I have never done it but it must work.

Comment: Thanks for awnser: it doesn't work, but i can build own decision - use sh-script, where i can run environment and "impala-shell"-action.